# Best workflow for iis an vs asp.net development

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I'm an asp.net developer, but I haven't found a good workflow for deployment.  Especially for small quick fixes that might not even require compiling.

The way I work now is to have two VS instances up while copy pasting a lot of code and files between the project and the folder on the IIS server.  Is there an automated process  that moves changes as I save in the VS project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, what you are doing is a pretty big no no for a lot of reasons.

When you make changes one of the big advantages ASP.Net has over something like PHP is simply that obvious problems (like misspelling a variable name) are caught during the build phase.  This is a huge benefit.

Next, if you are simply modifying a file and copying it's content to the server then it sounds like you are doing your testing *in production* instead of leveraging your local debugger.  Again, very bad practice.

Finally, VS includes a publish command.  The purpose of this is to compile and publish your site to the server.  It can do so through the regular file system, FTP, web deployment packages or even FPSE.  That last one is NOT recommended and is probably kept for backwards compatibility only.

Point is, develop and test locally.  When your ready for it to go to the server, use the publish command.